# Expand html table from two different php file

Tags: php, mysql

Need help...

I have 2 php file which are screen1.php and screen2.php

screen1.php consist of **main data** and screen2.php consist of **history** of main data.
Both main data and history store in 1 table.

How do I work if, i click main data in screen1.php it load history data from screen2.php into screen1.php

Thank you

Comment: what else you have tried yet?

Comment: i hv tried use javascript but not success..

Comment: right now i just combine to 1 page and try to do expand and collapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for Ajax.

You will need to include jquery library for this.

Page: main.php?user_id=4

```
<!----include Jquery library----->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!----include Jquery library----->

<title>Main Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php $sql="SELECT username, date, account_number, status
            FROM table WHERE user_id=" . $_GET['user_id'] ; 
//Do a prepared Statement to avoid SQL injection. Here I will just keep things simple
$user=$db->query($sql)->fetch();
?>    

<table width="100%" border="1" id="main">
  <tbody>
    <th colspan="4">Main Data</th>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><strong>Username</strong></td>
      <td align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
      <td align="center"><strong>Account Number</strong></td>
      <td align="center"><strong>Status</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $user['username']//James Bond ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $user['date']//18 Jan 2015 ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $user['account_number']//58241687929876 ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $user['status']//Active ?> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="view_more">View more</button><!---give button a id--->

<div id="history">
    <!------New data will be added here------>
</div>

<!------- THIS IS THE MAGIC PART ----------->
<script>
$(document).on('click','#view_more',function(){
               //Event,  button ID
    $.ajax({
        url:"view_history.php?user_id=<?php echo $_GET['user_id']; ?>"
        //Link to history.php. Pass user_id to url
        success:function(data){
            $('#history').empty();
            //empty history div if there is anything 
            $('#history').append(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
            //And then append new data
            }
        });
    });
</script>
 <!------- THIS IS THE MAGIC PART ----------->
</body>
```

Page: history.php

```
<?php 

$sql="SELECT type,date FROM table WHERE id=" . $_GET[user_id];
$history=$db->query($sql)->fetch();
?>

<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tbody>
      <th colspan="4">History of James Bond</th>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="50%"><strong>Type</strong></td>
      <td align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $history['type'];//Fund ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $history['date'];//18 Jan 2015 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $history['type'];//Refund ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $history['date'];//21 Jan 2014 ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $history['type'];//Refund ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $history['date'];//22 Jan 2014 ?> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please be careful take care of security measures.

Comment: hi.. i hv tried the code and i got this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object". Is it because of version.?? My PHP Version 5.3.1. thank you..

Comment: i solve the fatal error but there is new error which is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". Something here "success:function(data){" . Actually data refer to what??? Thank you.

Comment: It is because you are using it in a for loop. If you are trying to use it in a foreach loop, use `fecthAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: The problem is php. First assign $_GET to a variable. `<?php $user=isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $_GET['user_id'] : NULL;?>`. And then $.ajax change url to `"view_history.php?user_id=<?php echo $user; ?>"`. NOTICE the double quotes

Comment: i have another parts which is my data in while loop. and i have a link such as <a href="#?uid=<?php echo $uid;?>" id="view_more"><?php echo $uid;?></a>. how do i work to declare uid at javascript

Comment: if you want to get the value of `id="view_more"`, then you can do this `document.getElementById('view_more').innerHTML` or `$("#view_more").text()`

Comment: Also, if this answer helped, please select it as best answer or upvote.

Comment: if i  use document.getElementById('view_more').innerHTML or $("#view_more").text(), it is only show data at the first row but the next rows unable to read.

Comment: what is your while loop like. It should look something like this `while($row->fetch())`

Comment: this is my while loop while (list($id,$uid,$document_id,$activity,$date) = mysqli_fetch_row($res02))

Comment: Try this:`while($row = $res02->fetch_assoc()){echo $id;}`. Here is a example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo_table

Comment: Seem like both are same. I have 3 data (3 rows). every row shoud be able to click and expand the row. Right now only first row able to expand.the rest can't. why ya???

Comment: Oh I see. IDs are meant for one single element. Instead use class. Change `#view_more` to `.view_more`. And also don't forget to remove ID from the button and add `class="view_more"`.

Comment: ya...i have done as above. but no value come out. i also declare var param=document.getElementByClassName('view_more'); show some alert. but nothing happen. Is it my declaration wrong

Comment: Are you using a Wamp server?

Comment: Give me a while let me create a demo for you.

Comment: ya it works. I'm using var param= $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();//GET id of row. Tq very much..almost 1 week i'm looking the same part. you saved my life. thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

If all the data is in the same table then you just need to include the data in your query? If you wanted to keep your query simple you could use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)